# Facebook not including image on first share, after using debugger it's ok

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook Debugger for the URL's i try to share
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

`Show existing scrape information` gives me `Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped.` and when URL is shared, no thumbnail is shown.

However after using `Fetch new scrape information` I'm getting proper output, and the sharing is working fine.

This is not probably because of cache, because it happens also when appending random suffix to the URL.

How to fix the damn thing? Situation is weird, as the URL's title and description is parsed fine.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn't scrape information from your website each any every time you share a link. Facebook saves a cached copy of the information on the Facebook servers.

When you click "Fetch new scrape information" it forces Facebook to ignore the cached information and scrape your website immediately.

It sounds like you (or somebody) may have tried to share your URL on Facebook earlier, which has returned an error. Facebook remembered this error until you forced it to fetch new information.

It's perfectly normal so I wouldn't worry about it. Facebook would have refreshed it's cache of your page sooner or later and fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I try to add random suffix (like ?time=23425) to the URL it still doesn't scrape the information.

Comment: Send me a link to your website and I will have a look.